# Given differentiable $g:\Bbb R^2\to\Bbb R^2,\partial_vg(2,0)=(1,-1)$ and $g(2,0)=(\pi,0)$ compute $\partial_vf(2,0),$ where $f=g_1^2+\sin(g_1+g_2)$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, derivatives, solution-verification

> Let $v=\left(\frac12,-\frac{\sqrt 3}2\right)$ and $g:\Bbb R^2\to\Bbb R^2,g=(g_1,g_2)$ a differentiable function s. t. $g(2,0)=(\pi,0)$ and $\partial_vg(2,0)=(1,-1)$. Define a function $f:\Bbb R^2\to\Bbb R$ by $$f(x,y)=g_1(x,y)^2+\sin(g_1(x,y)+g_2(x,y)).$$
> Prove $f$ is differentiable at $(2,0)$ and compute $\partial_vf(2,0)$.

My attempt:

First, I noticed $\|v\|=\sqrt{\left(\frac12\right)^2+\left(-\frac{\sqrt 3}2\right)^2}=1$ and $g(2,0)=(\pi,0)\implies g_1(2,0)=\pi,g_2(2,0)=0.$

Therefore we can use the following result:

> Let $A\subseteq\Bbb R^n$ be an open set, $f:A\to\Bbb R^m$ and $v\in\Bbb R^n$ a unit vector. If $f$ is differentiable at $c,$ then $\partial_vf(c)$ exists and $\partial_vf(c)=Df(c)v.$

Also, we can apply the following lemma:

> Let $A\subseteq\Bbb R^n$ be an open set, $f:A\to\Bbb R^m,f=(f_1,\ldots,f_m)$ and $c\in A$. $f$ is differentiable at $c$ iff $f_i$ is differentiable $\forall i\in\{1,\ldots,m\}.$

This tells us both $g_1$ and $g_2$ are differentiable. Let $h:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R, h:t\mapsto t^2$ and $k:\Bbb R^2\to\Bbb R, k=g_1+g_2$. Then, $r=h\circ g_1$ and $s=\sin\circ k$ are both differentiable as compositions of differentiable functions, hence $f$ is also differentiable at $(2,0)$ and $$\begin{aligned}Df(2,0)&=Dh(g_1(2,0))Dg_1(2,0)+D\sin((g_1+g_2)(2,0))D(g_1+g_2)(2,0)\\&=2g_1(2,0)Dg_1(2,0)+\cos((g_1+g_2)(2,0))D(g_1+g_2)(2,0)\\&=2\pi Dg_1(2,0)-D(g_1+g_2)(2,0)\end{aligned}$$
In terms of matrices, $\operatorname{grad}g_i(2,0)=e_i^T\nabla g(2,0)$ and $\operatorname{grad}(g_1+g_2)(2,0)=(1,1)\nabla g(2,0).$

Finally,

$\begin{aligned}\partial_vf(2,0)&=\langle\operatorname{grad} f(2,0),v\rangle\\&=2\pi(1,0)\nabla g(2,0)v-(1,1)\nabla g(2,0)v\\&=2\pi(1,0)\partial_vg(2,0)-(1,1)\partial_vg(2,0)\\&=(2\pi,0)\cdot\begin{pmatrix}1\\-1\end{pmatrix}-(1,1)\begin{pmatrix}1\\-1\end{pmatrix}\\&=2\pi.\end{aligned}$

Can somebody verify my answer?

Comment: Your approach seems fine to me. Also the lemmas can be easily proved by contradiction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The approach has been verified in the comment section.